# Continuous numbering of theorems in report

Tags: numbering, theorems, report

I have a `report` class document with `sections` and `chapters`: `\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}`
And I need to add theorems  `\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}` under chapters

```
\begin{theorem}
Let $f$ be a function whose derivative exists in every point, then $f$ 
is a continuous function.
\end{theorem}
```

But right now theorems become numbered by number of the chapter like 1.1.1. and so on.

How could continuous numbering in report be achieved, so my theorems regardless of the chapter number were numbered like 1, 2, 3 etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]` (for example) will reset the `theorem` counter each time a new chapter is started.

Omitting `[chapter]` should provide continuous numbers.

If this doesn't help, use `\counterwithout{theorem}{chapter}` (requires `chngcntr` package)

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{chngcntr}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]

\counterwithout{theorem}{chapter}

\begin{document}

\chapter{First}

\begin{theorem}
Foo

\end{theorem}

\chapter{Second}

\begin{theorem}
Foobar

\end{theorem}

\chapter{Third}

\begin{theorem}
FoobarWins

\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Anuket: You're welcome. Happy TeXing!